# Set indexes for database used for login and register actions

Tags: mysql, database-design, index, optimization

I am thinking on how to set indexes to improve performance of a database for register and login actions.I have seen that alphabetical indexes are not good so I don't know how to do...Can you help me?In this type of databases what are the methods to implement performance?

Comment: I haven't written code yet because I don't know how to do.In that type of database generally what type of indexes are added?

Comment: Databases that have registered in them username of the users of a website or application.

Comment: I want to set a table named users.In this table there are a lot of rows.Each row is a user.Each row has some columns:Id, username,date of registration.i have thought that but I don't know if it is correct

Comment: To be even more specific - each index is useful for some queries and not for others so the exact structure together with the queries you need to execute are needed to decide what indexes to add.

Comment: I have thought to divide usernames in alphabetical order and set an index for all letters of the alphabet.

Comment: @Tovelo you do not "divide" the rows in the table for indexing, you just define the index over `username` column and let the system handle the sorting and storage of that index.

Comment: Setting an index in username's column,how the research will be done from the database?

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to have any indexes (Rather than primary key) for user table which is mainly used for authentication, because most of the fields in user table has unique rows (correct me if i am wrong), so Cardinality is very high. If you index high cardinality field it might be a performance hit. You can go through [this](https://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/what-makes-a-good-mysql-index-part-2-cardinality/) article for more information about cardinality and indexing

Comment: If I don't add index ,every time I search an username ,database will scan all rows...or not?

Comment: I agree that it search for all the rows. But check out the cardinality. If you add more and more rows you might end up with big performance hit

Comment: Ok,but if I want to add index the same,how can I do?What value can I take as reference?

Comment: @Nikesh high cardinality is *good*, it means the index is very effective in minimising the number of rows to read. Indexes on low-cardinality columns (for example yes/no column) are often pointless (but may be useful too if one of the values is present only on say 1% of rows to quickly filter out these 99% not needed by some queries).